# Can't access phpmyadmin after varnish install on ec2

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have installed varnish. For this, I have changed the apache port from 80 to 8080 and in my  varnish file config default.vcl I have this:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}


 ## Multiple virtual hosta
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
return(pass);
}


if (req.http.host ~ "mydomain.xxx(:[0-9]+)?$") {
 set req.backend = default;
 }



}
sub vcl_fetch {
if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
return (hit_for_pass);
}

}
```

but when I want to access phpmyadmin on `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/phpmyadmin`, I get no access.

Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access port 8080 externally you need to allow it on the security group that instance is using.

For example:

[image: Security Groups]

Comment: Thanks for your response , but i already did this but no result